# When I draw lines on PDF with iText7, some external receivers of pdf report not seeing the lines drawn

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I draw lines on a random PDF with iText7 with the following code:

```
private void DrawLines(PdfDocument document, int pageIndex, IEnumerable<Line> lines)
{
    var page = document.GetPage(pageIndex + 1);
    var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

    if (canvas == null)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Could not create PdfCanvas for page: {pageIndex}");
    }

    if (!lines.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        line.Scale(page);
        DrawLine(canvas, line);
    }
}

private void DrawLine(PdfCanvas canvas, Line line)
{
    canvas.SetLineWidth(line.BrushSize);
    canvas.SetStrokeColor(ColorConstants.BLACK);
    canvas.MoveTo(line.StartX, line.StartY);
    canvas.LineTo(line.EndX, line.EndY);
    canvas.ClosePathStroke();
}
```

When this document gets saved I see nice lines in my PDF just as I expect it to be.

Some external receivers of the pdfs report not seeing the lines at all and when they send us the document we see the lines being deleted.

How can I make sure the lines are not being deleted as an extra layer of some sorts.

Comment: What PDF reader are those users using / any hardware specifics? I can imagine a thin line being anti-aliased out by hardware accelerated graphics drivers / cards.

Comment: Just to be sure, please also share a PDF you created.

Comment: This is a very common problem and it has to do with fractional widths in lines with respect to the visual dpi. This can result in thicker/thin lines or even them disappearing. There are some PDF creators that use filled polygons to attempt to fix the issue.